# Laravel 6.5.2 error when registering on overwritten users table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I have overwritten the default user table with an existing table.
When trying to register a new user i get the following error:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\customUser given, called in {path}\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php on line 35

To overwrite the default users table with my own I have made the following changes:

```
///Auth.php///

//Auth defaults:
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'customusers',
    ],

//Auth guards:
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'customusers',
        ],

//User providers:
'providers' => [
        'customusers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\customUser::class,
        ],
```

I don't know if these changes could cause the error I'm facing.

The error is supposedly fired in this part of 'RegisterUsers.php'

```
$this->guard()->login($user);
```

This is part of the function 'register', which looks like this:

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
                        ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

Any help regarding this error would be kindly appreciated, I'm fairly new to Laravel so I would like to recieve a clear explanation to my problem so I can understand why it is calling this error.

Kind regards,
geertjanknapen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model needs to extend `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`, otherwise you cannot use it with the authentication methods like login / logout etc.

In your `customUser` model add the following:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class customUser extends Authenticatable
```

I would also recommend to rename your class `customUser` to `CustomUser` in order to follow [PSR-1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/):

> Class names MUST be declared in StudlyCaps.
>
> The term ‘StudlyCaps’ in PSR-1 MUST be interpreted as PascalCase where
>   the first letter of each word is capitalized including the very first
>   letter.

Answer (score 0):

On `RegisterUsers.php` you need to include

`use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;`

and below `class RegisterUsers extends Controller`

you need to add

`use AuthenticatesUsers;`

Comment: I think this is wrong. Is it that `CustomUser` needs to extend `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`?

Comment: maybe that's the one! One or the other anyway